# Multiple insert with seperate checkbox values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form containing 5 textareas and a checkbox next to each textarea.  The textarea and checkbox values are set to arrays.  I then loop through the array for the textarea and insert the records.  The textarea values are working fine, but the checkbox values aren't working as they need to.

The form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Submission</td>
    <td valign="top"><p>Allowed</p></td>
    <td valign="top">Comment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="13%" valign="top">Prescription</td>
    <td width="13%" align="center" valign="top"><input name="submission[]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    <td width="74%" valign="top"><textarea name="comment[]" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Lab Request</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><input name="submission[]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
    <td valign="top"><textarea name="comment[]" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Generic request</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><input name="submission[]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>
    <td valign="top"><textarea name="comment[]" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Image request</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><input name="submission[]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="3" /></td>
    <td valign="top"><textarea name="comment[]" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Stationery</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><input name="submission[]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="4" /></td>
    <td valign="top"><textarea name="comment[]" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="define_submissions" id="submit" value="Add Submissions" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The PHP:

```
$submission = intval($_POST['submission']);
$submission_comment = $_POST['comment'];


if(isset($_POST['define_submissions'])){ 

for($i=0, $count = count($submission_comment);$i<$count;$i++) {
    $comment = $submission_comment[$i];
    $query_level_1 = 
sprintf("INSERT INTO submission (             
           submission_pk,
           pathway_fk,
           submission_allowed,
           comment
        ) VALUES (
           '',
           '$pathway',
           '%s',
           '$comment')", $submission === $i ? 'y' : 'n');
$result_level_1 = mysql_query($query_level_1, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  (Hint: don't answer in a comment, [add it to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13945209/edit).)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, checkbox value are not sent to server, when not checked. So, you need to, first, check if it is exists / defined.

To make it easier, just add key value to your check box:

```
<input name="submission[0]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="0" />
<input name="submission[3]" id="submission_1" type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

And then, define the $submission:

```
$submissions = $_POST['submission'];
```

Inside for loop:

```
$submission = isset($submissions[$i]) ? 'n' : 'y';
```

And change your query line into:

```
'$comment')", $submission);
```